# Is itemprop="aggregateRating" obsolete?

Tags: html, schema.org, w3c-validation, microdata

I learned on this site that I should use:

```html
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
```

But the HTML checker says:

> The `itemprop` attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.

And all the `itemprop` attributes that follow get the same comment. If I remove the first `itemprop` then it's okay. I'm quit confused.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an item to which the `aggregateRating` property should be added to.

For example if it’s the rating of a [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha! The whole page is about the product (murderdinner). Should I begin the pagecontent with [code]<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">[/code] and add the itemprop="name" where name is "murderdinner"? I have added with the aggregateRating the itempro="name" as well (the same). Is that correct?

Comment: @LivingTale: You could also specify the `itemscope` (for `Product`) on the `body` element, or the `html` element, or an `article` element … whatever works best for you. The only thing that matters is that all properties (in `itemprop` attributes) that belong to this `Product` are descendants of that element, and of no other element with an `itemscope`. That means the `name` property for the `Product` may not be inside of the `AggregateRating` (this one could have another `name` property, giving the name of the rating instead of the product).

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/product#microdata

```
    <div itemtype="https://schema.org/Product" itemscope>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Executive Anvil" />
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveler looking for something to drop from a height." />
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope>
    <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="89" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.4" />
  </div>
```